# Is there a command I can run as a non-root user to see if a user can run a certain sudo command

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I maintain a bash script that performs a system check on any of our servers that I run it on. As part of this check, I need to make sure that a user named `monapp` can execute some commands:

`sudo /etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd restart`

`sudo /etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld restart`

`...`

However, I need to be able run this as a user who doesn't have access to the sudoers file. I also need to be able to figure out if the user can run these commands without executing them and parsing the output (i.e. I wouldn't want to restart apache on a bunch of systems just to see if `monapp` can restart it).

All of the solutions I have researched don't meet the above requirements, so I'm a little lost. Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you just attempt toexecute the command and handle potential failures?

Comment: No, that doesn't meet the requirements listed above. I don't want to restart Apache, for example, just to see if a user could...

Comment: Without any facts to back this up as such I would be very surprised if this was possible because you wouldn't really want to allow that sort of "sudo-accessible" command enumeration to users.

Comment: Can you try to run the `status` subcommands of those init.d scripts? That should tell you if you have access to sudo those scripts without actually doing anything noticeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up needing. Hope this helps someone in the future.

```
sudolist="$(sudo -l)"

declare -a commands=("/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld stop" "/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld start" 
                     "/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld restart" "/etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd stop" 
                     "/etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd start" "/etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd restart"
                     "/etc/rc.d/init.d/memcached stop" "/etc/rc.d/init.d/memcached start" 
                     "/etc/rc.d/init.d/memcached restart")

for i in "${commands[@]}"
do

    if [ ! -z "$(echo $sudolist | grep "$i")" ]; then
        echo -e "\tPASS: user can run '$i'"
    else
        echo -e "\tFAIL: user cannot run '$i'"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo -u theuser bash -c '[ -x /etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd ] && echo "OK" || echo "NOT"'
```

-x

check if file has execute permission (for the user running the test)

Then we run this command as the target user (theuser)